# Flash builder 4.6 : Error occured while taking APK build and also while debugging in device

Tags: air, flash-builder, flash-builder4.5

I'm using Flash builder 4.6 with Flex 4.6.0 SDK overlayed with AIR 3.8 SDK, i'm not able to take the export build and also not able to debug in mobile devices. I got an error while debugging in device.

**FB 4.6 ERROR LOG:**

```
dx tool failed:Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

java.lang.Exception
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.internal.FlexProjectCore.createErrorStatus(FlexProjectCore.java:1019)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.util.logging.GlobalLogImpl.log(GlobalLogImpl.java:66)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.util.logging.GlobalLog.log(GlobalLog.java:52)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.multisdk.apollo.export.AIRAPKPackager.create(AIRAPKPackager.java:190)
at com.adobe.flexide.multiplatform.android.launching.ADBLaunchHandler.doPackage(ADBLaunchHandler.java:447)
at com.adobe.flexide.multiplatform.android.launching.ADBLaunchHandler.launch(ADBLaunchHandler.java:250)
at com.adobe.flexide.launching.multiplatform.MultiPlatformLaunchDelegate.launch(MultiPlatformLaunchDelegate.java:191)
at com.adobe.flexide.launching.AbstractFlexLaunchDelegate.launch(AbstractFlexLaunchDelegate.java:244)
at com.adobe.flexide.launching.AbstractFlexLaunchDelegate.launch(AbstractFlexLaunchDelegate.java:134)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:854)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:928)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1132)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

I'm not facing this issue with my Flex 4.6.0 SDK. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is more a java environment issue related to your sdk 4.6 setup. How did you installed air 3.8 ? Also is this a big project? Have you tried to create a new small project with just a label inside ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my FlashBuilder 4.6 (Flex 4.6.0 SDK, AIR SDK 3.9)

Open your FlashBuilder.ini File and try changing the following values:

-Xms1520m
-Xmx1520m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:PermSize=64m

With this values I could solve this problem.
Best regards